# Using UITextView placeholder and not clearing text on re-entry

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uitextview

I'd like to have a placeholder in my UITextView and I'd rather avoid complexities like dragged out methods(overloaded code) and subclassing. I just need to retain **edit typing**.

I'm currently using this methodology to create a placeholder in an `UITextView`

.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *gcTextView;
```

.m

```
@synthesize gcTextView;
```

add this to to `viewDidLoad:`

```
self.gcTextView.text = @"placeholder text here";
self.gcTextView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
gcTextView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
```

Then use this method for editing->

```
- (void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *) textView
{
    [textView setText:@""];

    self.gcTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

*QUESTION:* What will I need to add to this way of doing it to

1) add the placeholder back to the `textView` if **edited text** returns to nil or `@""` I guess.

2) Not delete all the user's **edited text** when re-entering edit mode on the `textView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For having a placeholder functionality in `UITextView`, i generally do this:

```
[self.gcTextView setText:@"placeholder"];
[self.gcTextView setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[self.gcTextView setTag:100]; //start tag with default 100
```

---

```
- (void) textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *) textView
{
    if(textView.tag == 100) {
        [textView setTag:200];
        [textView setText:@""];
        [textView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor];
    }
}

- (void) textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *) textView
{
    //handle text that has spaces as it's content (i.e. no characters)
    NSString *strStrippedText = [textView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    if(strStrippedText.length == 0) {
        [textView setTag:100];
        [textView setText:@"Placeholder"];
        [textView setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
}
```

Basically, it's all about the tag I set to it

---

### **EDIT: However...**

If you use tags for other purposes then this might break something so you can safely modify the `bounces` property and use it as an indicator for your personal use.

```
[self.gcTextView setText:@"placeholder"];
[self.gcTextView setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[self.gcTextView setBounces:NO]; //NO for placeholder text
```

---

```
- (void) textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *) textView
{
    if(textView.bounces == NO) {
        [textView setText:@""];
        [textView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor];
        [textView setBounces:YES]; //YES for non-placeholder text
    }
}

- (void) textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *) textView
{
    //handle text that has spaces as it's content (i.e. no characters)
    NSString *strStrippedText = [textView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    if(strStrippedText.length == 0) {
        [textView setText:@"Placeholder"];
        [textView setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [textView setBounces:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: You're missing closing brackets.

Comment: VERY nice. I think this can also be done with booleans but this is really cool, haven't seen this

Comment: @WhiteHatPrince : glad you liked it :) ...tags to the rescue!

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the tag version (IOS 9) to following code.

```
- (BOOL) textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *) textView //changed to bool
{
    if(textView.tag == 100) {
        [textView setTag:200];
        [textView setText:@""];
        [textView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
    return YES; // added return value
}

- (void) textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *) textView
{
    //handle text that has spaces as it's content (i.e. no characters)
    NSString *strStrippedText = [textView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

    if(strStrippedText.length == 0) {
        [textView setText:UI_TEXT_HINT_BODY];
        [textView setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [textView setBounces:NO];
        [textView setTag:100]; // reset to hint mode
        }
}
```